# Email ext plugin to send HTML Junit reports in mail

Tags: plugins, jenkins, junit

I have used this below code in default content to generate text Junit        test reports.
${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="text"}
But now I wanted same in HTML format. I have changed content type to HTML and placed below code in default content -
${FILE,path="index.html"}
But I am getting html code in my email. Where did I miss ? Any Suggestions..

Comment: Are there config options in your e-mail client like _Display mail in plain text_ vs. _Display mail in HTML?_

Comment: I am using outlook.office365.com as mail web portal. I don't see any.

Comment: Also am getting this message in between of code " If you are seeing this, you are using non frame web client ".

Comment: Hi Abhishek, I have similar query, what you written in your index.html file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are seeing HTML code in you email, maybe you need to set the content type of the email to HTML(text/html).

You can change the Default Content Type to **HTML(text/html)** in the Jenkins System Configuration in the `Extended E-mail Notification` section.
Alternatively you can change the content type in the Job configuration.

Comment: I think you didn't notice in my query. I already did that but still am seeing html code in email.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Email ext plugin, then go to your workspace, there should be an 'emailable-report.html' generated. So set the correct path in default content like this:

```
${FILE,path="path/to/your/emailable-report.html"}
```

Comment: @ mainframer : Already given that in default content as specified in query.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of index.html , given path for those HTML files which are generated like all-tests.html. It worked fine. There may be a issue with frames.